# How to conver a XML file to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to convert a xml file to array list, but I don't know how.
This is how my xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<data>
   <record>
      <name> abc </name>
      <email> abc@abc </email>
   </record>
   <record>
      <name> asd </name>
      <email> asd@asd </email>
   </record>
      .
      .
      .
</data>
```

My array list built of Contact class, which looks like that:

```
public class Contact{
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public Contact(String name,String email){
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
    }
    public boolean contains(String str){
        return name.contains(str)|| email.contains(str);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name+"\n"+email;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I actually did it.
This is might be helpful for someone in the future.

```
private ArrayList<Contact> parse() throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
{
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    parser.setInput(getAssets().open("myxml.xml"),null);

    ArrayList<Contact> Contacts = null;
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    Contact con = null;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
        String name;
        switch (eventType){
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                Contacts = new ArrayList();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("record"))
                    con = new Contact();
                else if (con != null){
                    if (name.equals("name"))
                        con.name = parser.nextText();
                    else if (name.equals("email"))
                        con.email= parser.nextText();
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("record") && con != null)
                    Contacts.add(con);
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    return Contacts;

}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAXB... Unmarshling to convert xml to java object

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"        standalone="true"?>
 <Question>

    <id>1</id>

 <Question>
 ....    
 .....
```

Question.java

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;  
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;  

  @XmlRootElement  
  public class Question {  
  private int id; 

  @XmlAttribute  
  public int getId() {  
  return id;  
  }  

  public void setId(int id) {  
  this.id = id;  
  }  
 }
```

Main method

```
    try { 
    File file = new File("question.xml");  
    JAXBContext jaxbContext =    JAXBContext.newInstance(Question.class);  

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller =  jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
    Question que= (Question) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  

    System.out.println(que.getId());
    System.out.println("Answers:");  
    List<Answer> list=que.getAnswers();  
    for(Answer ans:list)  
      System.out.println(ans.getId());  

  } catch (JAXBException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
  }
```

Steps to convert XML document into java object.

```
  1.Create POJO or bind the schema and generate the classes.
  2.Create the JAXBContext object.
  3.Create the Unmarshaller objects.
  4.Call the unmarshal method.
  5.Use getter methods of POJO to access the data.
```